# ConTeXt: Circumventing pandoc's deprecated starttable usage

Tags: tables, context, pandoc, filter

## Background

A wiki generates an HTML page, which is converted to ConTeXt via pandoc. The ultimate goal is to generate a PDF from on a wiki page using XWiki, which is a Java-based tool.

## Problem

Pandoc uses [starttable](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/starttable), which is a [deprecated table syntax](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2102) and severely hampers formatting the table. The tables do not respect text margins, even when using `\setuptables[textwidth=\textwidth]`, producing illegible results such as:

[image: Text margins fail]

## Code

The code generated by pandoc:

```
\placetable[none]{}
\starttable[|l|l|]
\HL
\NC {\bf Term}
\NC {\bf Definition}
\NC\AR
\NC ERD
\NC Entity-Relationship Diagram
\NC\AR
\NC ETL
\NC Extract, Transform, and Load
\NC\AR
\HL
\stoptable
```

This code cannot be changed -- it's what comes out of pandoc and is dependent on the information stored in a wiki page. If a user decides to update the wiki page, then the content generated by pandoc will differ. That is, no TeX code is edited by hand, only machine processed.

## Questions

Short of writing a [pandoc filter](https://github.com/Vinai/pandocfilters-php/blob/master/pandocfilters.php) or fixing pandoc, can the `\starttable` macro (including its [basic commands](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/index.php?title=Table&redirect=no#Basic_Commands)) be overwritten to employ [xtables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/xtables) or [natural tables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE)?

On a related note, how can generated column widths be suppressed using pandoc? That is:

- Before: `\starttable[|l(0.2\textwidth)|l(0.8\textwidth)|]`
- After: `\starttable[|l|l|]`

It could turn out that suppressing the widths is irrelevant if a solution is presented that redefines the \starttable macro (and its companion commands).

## Environment

- pandoc v2.0.6
- ConTeXt MKIV v2018.01.04 17:37

## Related

Related questions include:

- [Why are my tables running off the edge of the page in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78385/2148)

Comment: `\setuptables[textwidth=\textwidth]` only applies to variable width columns.  What is the problem with fixing pandoc?

Comment: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/4223

Comment: I wrote an extension for the pandoc ConTeXt writer to write Natural Tables instead of Extreme Tables: `pandoc -f markdown -t context+ntb -o test.tex test.md`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Pull Request

> ConTeXt writer: Use xtables instead of Tables [#4223](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/4223)

has been merged into the `master` branch and will thus be part of the next release of pandoc.

## Extreme Tables

The Markdown input

```markdown
| Field             | Entity              | Column                 | Notes            |
|-------------------|---------------------|------------------------|------------------|
| Level             | COGNITIVE_LEVEL     | LEVEL                  | Via ASSESSMENT   |
| **Count** / Total | ASSESSMENT_ANSWER   | ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID | Count the number |
| Count / **Total** | ASSESSMENT_QUESTION | ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID | Count the number |
```

Can then be processed using

```bash
pandoc -f markdown -t context -o test.tex test.md
```

to generate Extreme Tables

```
\startplacetable[location=none]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell Field \stopxcell
\startxcell Entity \stopxcell
\startxcell Column \stopxcell
\startxcell Notes \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\startxrow
\startxcell Level \stopxcell
\startxcell COGNITIVE_LEVEL \stopxcell
\startxcell LEVEL \stopxcell
\startxcell Via ASSESSMENT \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
\startxcell {\bf Count} / Total \stopxcell
\startxcell ASSESSMENT_ANSWER \stopxcell
\startxcell ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID \stopxcell
\startxcell Count the number \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablebody
\startxtablefoot[foot]
\startxrow
\startxcell Count / {\bf Total} \stopxcell
\startxcell ASSESSMENT_QUESTION \stopxcell
\startxcell ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID \stopxcell
\startxcell Count the number \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablefoot
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable
```

The local setups `head`, `body`, and `foot` are predefined in the pandoc standalone template.  If the standalone version is not used, add `\setupxtable[head,body,foot][]` to your document.  Shown below is the output of the standalone template.

[image]

## Natural Tables

For maximum flexibility an extension to write Natural Tables instead is provided.  It can be activated by adding `+ntb` to the ConTeXt writer.

```bash
pandoc -f markdown -t context+ntb -o test.tex test.md
```

This generates

```
\startplacetable[location=none]
\startTABLE
\startTABLEhead
\NC Field
\NC Entity
\NC Column
\NC Notes
\NC\NR
\stopTABLEhead
\startTABLEbody
\NC Level
\NC COGNITIVE_LEVEL
\NC LEVEL
\NC Via ASSESSMENT
\NC\NR
\NC {\bf Count} / Total
\NC ASSESSMENT_ANSWER
\NC ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID
\NC Count the number
\NC\NR
\stopTABLEbody
\startTABLEfoot
\NC Count / {\bf Total}
\NC ASSESSMENT_QUESTION
\NC ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID
\NC Count the number
\NC\NR
\stopTABLEfoot
\stopTABLE
\stopplacetable
```

[image]

Comment: As a minor technical note, the last row isn't always a table footer (i.e., a columnar summary), which is a bit misleading, semantically speaking.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Prepare your pull request and send it to the pandoc repository.