# Setup a distance between columns in tabulate for ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context, fill

I need to create a simple block showing recipe content. A tabulate seems as the easiest way to do that. Below is an example of what I mean

```
\starttext

\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hbox to 0.3em{\hss.\hss}\hfill}

\starttabulate[|p|l|Il|]
    \NC Item 1                  \leaderfill     200 \NC     \NC g   \NR
    \NC Item Item 2             \leaderfill     60  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
    \NC Item Item Item Item 3   \leaderfill     10  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
    \NC Item Item 4             \leaderfill     0   \NC.5   \NC g   \NR
    \NC Item Item 5             \leaderfill     0   \NC.25  \NC g   \NR
    \NC Very very very long name of Item 6          \NC     \NC     \NR
    \NC the rest of the name    \leaderfill 10--15  \NC     \NC pcs.\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

To make fractions look correct, I need to remove the distance between the first and second columns (set zero width) and set the distance between the second and third ones equal to the width of a space character.

I've reviewed the [Why are my tables running off the edge of the page in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78385/why-are-my-tables-running-off-the-edge-of-the-page-in-context) topic, however, it hasn't helped me. Using `o0` and `s0` are break my table:

```
\starttabulate[o0|p|l|Il|]
    \NC Item 1                  \leaderfill     200 \NC     \NC g   \NR
    \NC Item Item 2             \leaderfill     60  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
    \NC Item Item Item Item 3   \leaderfill     10  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
    \NC Item Item 4             \leaderfill     0   \NC.5   \NC g   \NR
    \NC Item Item 5             \leaderfill     0   \NC.25  \NC g   \NR
    \NC Very very very long name of Item 6          \NC     \NC     \NR
    \NC the rest of the name    \leaderfill 10--15  \NC     \NC pcs.\NR
\stoptabulate
```

[image]

Using a fixed width for columns is undesirable since tables may be used in various width parent environments.

So, how can I set up a distance between columns in tabulate?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

You can use `i` and `j` to set space between columns, see the [context garden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/starttabulate).

This could be what you want (but have a look at the link above and play with the keys):

```
\starttabulate[|pj0|i0l|Il|]
     \NC Item 1                  \leaderfill     200 \NC     \NC g   \NR
     \NC Item Item 2             \leaderfill     60  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
     \NC Item Item Item Item 3   \leaderfill     10  \NC     \NC ml  \NR
     \NC Item Item 4             \leaderfill     0   \NC.5   \NC g   \NR
     \NC Item Item 5             \leaderfill     0   \NC.25  \NC g   \NR
     \NC Very very very long name of Item 6          \NC     \NC     \NR
     \NC the rest of the name    \leaderfill 10--15  \NC     \NC pcs.\NR
\stoptabulate
```

The output becomes (I used A5 paper to get a slightly tighter page):

[image: the table]

One could think of using the units module (or at least roman) for the units.